# Implementing ActionBar tabs with v4 Fragments API

Tags: android, tabs, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

My app is currently using the Fragments/v4 compatibility package to support Android versions all the way down to 1.6. This means all my Fragments inherit from the compatibility package's version of `Fragment`. I'm currently trying to rework parts of the app to take advantage of Honeycomb features, like `ActionBar`.

I already use my own action-bar-like implementation on pre-3.0 devices, and the Honeycomb Action Bar otherwise. This bit isn't an issue.

The problem I have is trying to implement tabs using the ActionBar. `ActionBar.TabListener` expects the native `Fragment` and `FragmentTransaction` classes to work - so trying to use my Fragment classes (which inherit from the compatibility library) doesn't compile.

So, does anyone have any ideas how I can use fragments that use the compatibility package version of `Fragment` with `ActionBar` tabs?

tldr: how can I use ActionBar tabs with fragments that inherit from the v4 compatibility library?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I asked this question on the android-developers mailing list.

The approach I've taken is the one suggested by CommonsWare, whereby the provided FragmentTransaction parameter is ignored entirely:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/d8d84cdd2f753b71

Comment: Seems like a working solution but the Support Package will pollute our apps like forever this way... I don't think that Gingerbread and Froyo  will decrease down to 10% before 2014

Comment: According to the last post in that thread, I start looking into ActionBarSherlock, which seems more promising than the counterparts in official v4 compatibility lib.